# Just linking with libavformat make valgrind report possibly lost, should I worry?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, libavformat

I have this test program:

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

AVFormatContext * formatContext = NULL;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    if( formatContext ) {
        avformat_free_context( formatContext );
        formatContext = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It just does nothing as `formatContext` pointer is null, it just make sure linker bind with libavformat.

compiled with `gcc -o testmem src/main.c -lavformat`

And checking with `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --show-leak-kinds=all ./testmem`

Report:

```
==13956== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13956==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13956==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13956==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
==13956==    still reachable: 48,092 bytes in 233 blocks
==13956==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==13956==                         newarray           : 1,536 bytes in 16 blocks
==13956==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13956== 
==13956== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==13956== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I understand it as "libavformat have some uninitialized pointer pointing at nothing".

Is there a missing ffmpeg cleanup function in my test program ?

Is this normal and I shall use a less paranoid set of options with valgrind ?

Comment: You will need to decide. If it's a one-off allocation (such as a cache) that isn't being freed then it is fairly safe to ignore. I prefer to use a suppression file in this case. If you don't keep on top of leaks (even small ones) you soon get huge numbers being reported and it will be difficult to see the woods for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

After following @Paul advice I ended up using this *valgrind* suppression file.

```
{
   A
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.*
   ...
}

{
   B
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   obj:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
   ...
}
```

with
`valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --suppressions=testmem.supp ./testmem`

I guess it's kind of specific to dev env.